# React Redux Axios error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, axios

I get error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"** when I want to save data about customer.

In my **customerApi.js** there is function updateCustomer and when I use this function in **customerActions.js** I get the error above

```
export function updateCustomer(customer){
   axios.put(`/api/customers/${customer.id}`, {customer});
}
```

In my customerActions.js

```
export function updateCustomer(customer) {
  return function(dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(beginApiCall());
      return customerApi.updateCustomer(customer)
     /* 
        IT WORKING
     return axios.put(`/api/customers/${customer.id}`, customer)
      */  
        .then(updatedCustomer => {
          dispatch(updateCustomerSuccess(updatedCustomer))
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch(apiCallError(error));
          throw error;
        })
   
    
  };
}
```

It working when I set **return axios.put(`/api/customers/${customer.id}`, customer)**  instead of **return customerApi.updateCustomer(customer)**.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to resolve this situation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your first `updateCustomer` function needs to return the axios promise. Currently it returns nothing.

Comment: @George Thanks for tip, I set axios promises(async-await) and it works.